# How include a custom form to be render in a Modal

Tags: forms, kentico

Hello I'm trying to include in a modal a custom form (is not a BizKentico Form) when it is rendered the tag `<form>` is missing and when click submit buttom it realod the page and lose de input data before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Portal engine or MVC?
If you are using Portal, Kentico wraps the entire page in a form tag. You can hack it buy doing something like this, but it may cause some issues on the page.

```
</form>
<form> 
your form data 
</form>
<form>
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for help me, this idea was great!